# How do I set up a WiFi to wired router?

Tags: router, wifi-configuration

I need to set up a router to get an upstream WiFi connection and transmit it over Ethernet.

I don't have hardware to do this yet so I can buy hardware within reason.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your intention is to wire is some devices over ethernet to a router, that will itself be a wireless client to another wireless router, then what you are trying to do is create a wireless bridge.

Not all consumer routers will let you do this, so i would suggest one of 2 things.  A. do your research for any model you're looking at buying new and see if it can be set up as a wireless bridge (or wireless client)  B.  find yourself a router on this list [DD-WRT compatible routers](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) and flash it with DD-WRT then read the wiki on creating a wireless bridge [here](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge).

It's a fairly straightforward network setup, it boils down to personal preference for hardware, ease of setup, and overall desired use.

Comment: Thanks! Will select something from that list. Any personal suggestions as to what?

Comment: nothing current, I haven't experimented with any new consumer routers in the past 5 years or so.  waiting until current hardware dies.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called an "AP Client".  Generally better routers have this functionality - just look for it.   As @TimmyBrowne said, routers which run dd-wrt can do this.